# Django: get profiles having auth.Group as foreign key

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication, django-users

I have an model which uses `auth.models.Group` as foreign key called Dashboard:

```
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    d_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    d_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    d_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    d_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def __str__(self):return self.d_name
```

my `views.py` is:

```
def custom_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboards')        
    return login(request, 'login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)

def custom_logout(request):
    return logout(request, next_page='/')

def user(request):
    context = {'user': user, 'groups': request.user.groups.all()}
    return render_to_response('registration/dashboards.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and here using this `dashboards.html` I want to display the dashboards by using the Group_name which i will get as a result of **group.name**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.get_username }}. <br/>
    {% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}

<ul>
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>
        <strong>{{ group.name }}<strong> -

            {{ dashboards.d_name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}

    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>



{% endblock %}
```

here I have mentioned all the supporting information for my problem, please let me know if there are any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the list of `Dashboard`s for the `Group` use the `group.dashboard_set` queryset:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>
        <strong>{{ group.name }}</strong> -
        {% for dashboard in group.dashboard_set.all %}
            {{ dashboard.d_name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This queryset is called "[backward relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)".

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```html
def user(request):
    user= request.user
    groups = request.user.groups.all()
    dashboards = Dashboard.objects.filter(owner=groups)

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'groups': groups,
        'dashboards': dashboards,
    }
    return render_to_response('registration/dashboards.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and dashboards.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.get_username }}. <br/>
    {% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}

<ul>
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>
        <strong>you belongs to::{{ group.name }}</strong> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<strong>#Dashboards available are::</strong>
{% for Dashboard in dashboards %}
    <ol>
 <li>{{ Dashboard.d_name }}-{{ Dashboard.owner }}-{{Dashboard.d_description}}</li> </ol>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

this works good and neat,,,,